OpenIdConnect not working after deployment of blazor server app
The Blazor server application is working locally with a locally stored certificate. But the application is not working in the Azure portal, it keeps on showing pick an account dialogue. Application is registered in Microsoft Entra ID. Application is added as managed identity in keyvault access. Return URL is set in app registration.
This is program.cs
using CertificateAuth.Server.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyComponents();



builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "User.Read", "User.Read.All" })
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("MicrosoftGraph"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();

builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.FallbackPolicy = options.DefaultPolicy;
});

builder.Services.AddRazorComponents()
    .AddInteractiveServerComponents();

builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error", createScopeForErrors: true);
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseAntiforgery();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(CertificateAuth.Client._Imports).Assembly);

app.Run();

This is my appsettings.json for the deployed app
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "xxxx.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "730237e0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-ccb0e9661c1e",
    "ClientId": "df903d59-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-b55c1c3db538",
    "ClientCertificates": [
      {
        "SourceType": "KeyVault",
        "KeyVaultUrl": "https://kvxxxxx.vault.azure.net/",
        "CertificateName": "certificateauthsample"
      }
    ],
    "ValidateAuthority": true,
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "MicrosoftGraph": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "User.Read.All"
  }
}


Authentication setting in EntraId

Certificate in EntraId

Certificate in Keyvault

Kayvault access policy

API Permissions in EntraId


Kudu application log


2024-08-30 11:33:54.484 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler: Exception occurred while processing message.
System.ArgumentException: IDW10109: All client certificates passed to the configuration have expired or can't be loaded.  (Parameter 'clientCredentials')
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilderExtension.WithClientCredentialsAsync(ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder builder, IEnumerable1 clientCredentials, ILogger logger, ICredentialsLoader credentialsLoader, CredentialSourceLoaderParameters credentialSourceLoaderParameters) at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.BuildConfidentialClientApplicationAsync(MergedOptions mergedOptions) at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetOrBuildConfidentialClientApplicationAsync(MergedOptions mergedOptions) at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.AddAccountToCacheFromAuthorizationCodeAsync(AuthCodeRedemptionParameters authCodeRedemptionParameters) at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisitionAspNetCore.AddAccountToCacheFromAuthorizationCodeAsync(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context, IEnumerable1 scopes, String authenticationScheme)
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthenticationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RunAuthorizationCodeReceivedEventAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage authorizationResponse, ClaimsPrincipal user, AuthenticationProperties properties, JwtSecurityToken jwt)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
2024-08-30 11:33:54.488 +00:00 [Error] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware: An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationFailureException: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
---> System.ArgumentException: IDW10109: All client certificates passed to the configuration have expired or can't be loaded.  (Parameter 'clientCredentials')
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilderExtension.WithClientCredentialsAsync(ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder builder, IEnumerable1 clientCredentials, ILogger logger, ICredentialsLoader credentialsLoader, CredentialSourceLoaderParameters credentialSourceLoaderParameters) at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.BuildConfidentialClientApplicationAsync(MergedOptions mergedOptions) at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.GetOrBuildConfidentialClientApplicationAsync(MergedOptions mergedOptions) at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition.AddAccountToCacheFromAuthorizationCodeAsync(AuthCodeRedemptionParameters authCodeRedemptionParameters) at Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisitionAspNetCore.AddAccountToCacheFromAuthorizationCodeAsync(AuthorizationCodeReceivedContext context, IEnumerable1 scopes, String authenticationScheme)
at Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthenticationBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.<b__1>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.RunAuthorizationCodeReceivedEventAsync(OpenIdConnectMessage authorizationResponse, ClaimsPrincipal user, AuthenticationProperties properties, JwtSecurityToken jwt)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.HandleRemoteAuthenticateAsync()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl.g__Awaited|10_0(ExceptionHandlerMiddlewareImpl middleware, HttpContext context, Task task)

Please copy the url or share the network trace with us, I want to check what the redirect url is.

We also can check the sign-in logs in azure portal, I believe there is no success logs in it (after deploying). And we also can enable the asp.net core logging feature to check waht happened.

@JasonPan please check updated info.

Hi Sivakumar, according to the error message(IDW10109: All client certificates passed to the configuration have expired or can't be loaded), please check  the validity period of the certificateauthsample certificate.

@JasonPan certificate is valid until 2034, the screen shot attached above. The same certificate is working locally.

Please see this link if it's helpful: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/wiki/Using-certificates#getting-certificates-from-key-vault. You would have to set the AZURE_CLIENT_ID environment variable to the user-assigned managed client ID in Azure portal.

Could you also check your appsettings.json's ClientCertificates and make sure your KeyVaultCertificateName is set correct.
